# Replace values in dataframe with difference to last row value by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, difference

I'm trying to replace every value above 1000 in my dataframe by its difference to the previous row value.

This is the way I tried with pandas:

```py
data_df.replace(data_df.where(data_df["value"] >= 1000), data_df["value"].diff(), inplace=True)
```

This does not result in an error, but nothing in the dataframe changes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'value': [1000, 200002,50004,600005], }
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

data_df["diff"] =  data_df["value"].diff()
data_df["value"] = np.where((data_df["value"]>10000) ,data_df["diff"],data_df["value"])

data_df.drop(columns='diff', inplace=True)
```

I introduce one column "diff" to get the difference of pervious row.
`np.where` allow u implement the if else statement.

Hope it helps u thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `freq` to 1000 or whatever interval you want.  I have it at 10 to make the sample easier to see.  Basically shifting the row, and for every row where the index is evenly divisible by the frequency, use the shifted value, otherwise leave as is.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

freq = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[x for x in range(30)]})
df['previous'] = df['data'].shift(1)

df['data'] = np.where((df.index % freq==0) & (df.index>0), df['data'] -df['previous'], df['data'])

df.drop(columns='previous', inplace=True)
```

Output

```
    data
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   3.0
4   4.0
5   5.0
6   6.0
7   7.0
8   8.0
9   9.0
10  1.0
11  11.0
12  12.0
13  13.0
14  14.0
15  15.0
16  16.0
17  17.0
18  18.0
19  19.0
20  1.0
21  21.0
22  22.0
23  23.0
24  24.0
25  25.0
26  26.0
27  27.0
28  28.0
29  29.0
```

Comment: @yarvis Feel free to upvote and accept as the correct answer so that others may find it in the future!  Thanks

Comment: cant upvote sadly. Not enough reputation.

Comment: @yarvis no problem!  Glad it helped.